# How can I change the template with ui-router depending on the value of a passed param?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I set up the following:

```
   var questionsContent = {
        name: 'questions.content',
        parent: 'questions',
        url: '/:question',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: '/Content/app/questions/partials/content.html',
                controller: 'QuestionsContentController',
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would really like is if the value of :question is a number for it to use the template   questionDetail.html and if not a number then content.html

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
   var questionsContent = {
        name: 'questions.content',
        parent: 'questions',
        url: '/:question',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
                    var isNumber = !isNaN(parseFloat(stateParams.question)); 
                    return isNumber ? 'questionDetail.html' : 'content.html'
                },
                controller: 'QuestionsContentController',
            }
        }
    }
```